# How to store Latitude and Longitude details in the database and retrive the details in a ListView

Tags: android

I have done using SQLite but I am unable to store the values. I checked this through retrieving values through `ListView`. Can anybody help? A am struck with this project.

```
package com.mahesh.map2;
public class history extends ListActivity {

    //private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = null;

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    // private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";

    private static String DBNAME = "locationmarkersqlite";

    /** Field 1 of the table locations, which is the primary key */
    public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";

    /** Field 2 of the table locations, stores the latitude */
    public static final String FIELD_LAT = "lat";

    /** Field 3 of the table locations, stores the longitude*/
    public static final String FIELD_LNG = "lng";

    /** Field 4 of the table locations, stores the zoom level of map*/
    public static final String FIELD_ZOOM = "zom";

    /** A constant, stores the the table name */
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";

    /** An instance variable for SQLiteDatabase */
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openAndQueryDatabase();

        displayResultList();


    }
    private void displayResultList() {
        TextView tView = new TextView(this);
        tView.setText("This data is retrieved from the database and only 4 " +
                "of the results are displayed");
        getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }
    private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
        try {
            LocationsDB dbHelper = new LocationsDB(this.getApplicationContext());
            mDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            //double latitude;
            //double longitude;
            Cursor c = mDB.query("locations", new String[]{
                     "latitude", "longitude"}, null, null,
                    null, null, null);
            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                    //  String title = c.String(c
                     //           .getColumnIndex("title"));
                     //   String description = c.String(c
                      //          .getColumnIndex("description"));
                        int latitude = (int) (c.getDouble(c
                                .getColumnIndex("latitude")) * 1E6);
                        int longitude = (int) (c.getDouble(c
                                .getColumnIndex("longitude")) * 1E6);
                        results.add("FIELD_LNG" + latitude + ",FIELD_LAT " + longitude);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }           
        } catch (SQLiteException e ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (mDB != null) 
                mDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE);
                mDB.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you creating the database??

Answer (score 0):

I am using ORMLite library to manage Db stuff. It's quite easy to get it going, should not take more than 4 hours, but it will be very valuable in future. First, you have you have to create some object you want to store in db and add annotations, so that ORMLite knows what and how to store.

```
public class MyTableRow {
    @DatabaseField
    long longitude;
    @DatabaseField
    long latitude;
    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    int id;
    public MyTableRow(long lon,long lat){..};
}
```

After that, create connection source:

```
MySqliteOpenHelper dbHelper = null;
                AndroidConnectionSource connectionSource = null;
                if (dbHelper == null || connectionSource == null) {
                    dbHelper = new MySqliteOpenHelper(context, null, null,
                            0);
                    connectionSource = new AndroidConnectionSource(dbHelper);
                }
```

MySqliteOpenHelper can be a simple config class, with db name and version:

```
public class MySqliteOpenHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public MySqliteOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName,
        CursorFactory factory, int databaseVersion) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,
        ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Once those are set up, you can start creating tables and inserting and retrieving data:

```
public static void createTables(ConnectionSource connectionSource,
        Class<?>... classes) {
    for (Class<?> c : classes) {
        try {
            TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, c);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
private static <T> void doInserts(ConnectionSource connectionSource,
        Class<T> object, List<T> objects)
        throws SQLException {
            final Dao<T, String> dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource,
            object);

    for (T data : objects) {
        dao.createOrUpdate(data);
    }

}
public static <T> List<T> getTable(Class<T> objectClass,
        Context context) {
    MySqliteOpenHelper sqliteDbHelper = new MySqliteOpenHelper(context,
            null, null, 0);
    ConnectionSource connectionSource = new AndroidConnectionSource(
            sqliteDbHelper);

    List<T> mList;
    try {
        Dao<T, String> mDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource,
                objectClass);
            mList = mDao.queryForAll();
        return mList;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: can u plz tell me how to store the latitude and logitude details into the sqlite database i tried but it is not opening

Comment: Download Core and Android ORMLite from [here](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml)

Place both jars in Eclipse libs folder. After that, take the code I provided, adapt it for yourself. After that, put lat/long in wrapper object, and add that object to a list: `myObjectList.add(new MyTableRow(lat,long);` and insert into db `doInserts(source,MyTableRow.class,myObjectList);`. Retrieve data `dataFromDb = getTable(MyTableRow.class,someContext);`.